# swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens

Tags: uniswap, sushiswap

According to Uniswap, we need to use `swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens` for tokens that take a fee on transfer. My question is, when does this token fee paid? Also, how does this mechanism work in code?

It would be great if someone could point out example; there is barely anything on google.